# Finding an item in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
$LogsPath = '\\someserver\somepath\*'
$LogsProperties = Get-ChildItem -Path $LogsPath -recurse |
Select-String -Pattern '[a-z]' |
Select-Object -Property Filename, Path, Line

$Array = @()
$LogsProperties | foreach {
$Array += $LogsProperties
}
```

The query above will create an array with the following values

(dashes are tabs/columns)

> Filename--------------------------Path--------------------------------------------------------------Line
>
> FName1 LName1.txt-----------\\someserver\somepath\FName1
>   LName1.txt-----------XXX Value
>   FName2 LName2.txt-----------\\someserver\somepath\FName1
>   LName1.txt-----------YYY Value
>   FName3 LName3.txt-----------\\someserver\somepath\FName1
>   LName1.txt-----------ZZZ Value

```
$Array[0]
```

Returns:

> FName1 LName1.txt-----------\\someserver\somepath\FName1
>   LName1.txt-----------XXX Value

Can someone tell me how to search for the index of an element using a value

The function below doesn't work for me

```
$array.indexof('XXX Value')
0 <-- expected result, index of the array
```

and will return the error below

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a
>   method named 'indexof'. At line:20 char:15
>   + $array.indexof <<<< ('XXX Value')
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (indexof:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [Maximilian Burszley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52236665/45375), `$LogsProperties` is already an array, whose elements are `[pscustomobject]` instances with properties `FileName`, `Path`, and `Line`.

(Your attempt to create `$Array` from `$LogsProperties` is not only unnecessary, but also broken, because the elements of `$Array` all end up referencing the array referenced by `$LogsProperties` as a whole.)

In order to use the `.IndexOf()` method on array instances<sup>[1]</sup>, **PSv3+** is required.
PSv3+ also allows you to use [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), so you can apply `.IndexOf()` to `$LogsProperties.Line` in order to search the array of `.Line` property values:

```sh
$LogsProperties.Line.IndexOf('XXX Value') # -> 0
```

In **PSv2** you can use a `foreach` loop to determine the index:

```sh
$i = 0
foreach ($obj in $LogsProperties) { if ($obj.Line -eq 'XXX Value') { break }; ++$i }
if ($i -eq $LogsProperties.Count) { $i = -1 }
# $i now contains the index of the matching element or -1, if not found.
```

---

<sup>[1] Type `System.Array`, the base type for all arrays, also has [a *static* `.IndexOf()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-2.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_) that is available in PSv2 too. However, given the need to search the `.Line` property values of the array elements of `$LogProperties`, that won't help here, unless a separate array with just the `.Line` property values is constructed first.</sup>

Comment: Utilizing the foreach loop, instead of `break` he could start another variable as such `[string[]]$index += "$i"` to create an array of index's that all contain the search criteria, instead of just the first one. (if that's his goal)... I would also put a `$index = $null` under `$i = 0`

Comment: Thanks, @RobertCotterman. Given that the OP tried to use `.IndexOf()`, which only ever returns the _first_ match, I've restricted my `foreach` loop to the same behavior. In the same vein I've just added code to set `$i` to `-1` if no match is found.

Answer (score 1):

So your `$logsProperties` is *already* an array.  You can filter using `Where-Object` or the `Where` array method:

```
$logsProperties = Get-ChildItem -Path \\someserver\somepath\* -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern '[a-z]' |
    Select-Object -Property FileName, Path, Line
```

---

Filtering:

```
$logsProperties | Where-Object Line -like '*xxx value*'
```

or:

```
$logsProperties.Where{$_.Line -like '*xxx value*'}
```

Comment: This returns the array value not the index of the result :(

Comment: @ByronMadison Why do you *need* the index?

Comment: I want to call the value of the index, part of a wider plan for the script. I want to get the path and compare it to something else